# Javascript webpack import class from third library

Tags: javascript, webpack

When I add the QRCode.js library with inline javascript

```
<script src="qrcode.js"> </script>
```

I can use the QRCode constructor like so

```
let qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), {
        text: "http://jindo.dev.naver.com/collie",
        width: 128,
        height: 128,
        colorDark : "#000000",
        colorLight : "#ffffff",
        correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
    });
```

I've also added the qrcode library to my node_modules, but when I try to import it using webpack

```
import { QRCode } from 'qrcodejs'
```

I get an `TypeError: qrcodejs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.QRCode is not a constructor`

How do I import QRCode with webpack, so I can use the constructor to create QRCodes?

Please let me know if I need to provide more information. I am using vanilla Javascript trying to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
import QRCode from "qrcode";
```

Comment: qrcode does not exist the package is called qrcodejs in my node_modules

Comment: If you still didn't managed to fix it, try using this one https://github.com/soldair/node-qrcode